# Preventing page to be cached on browsers after redirection in ASP.NET MVC Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there any way that I can prevent user to go back to the navigation in all browsers. I.e preventing browsers to store my previous page in cache, so that user cannot navigate back to the previous page.
I used `RedirectToAction()` method from `Asp.Net MVC Core` library?

Comment: Really not possible.

Comment: I believe you're asking for the `replace` option. Not sure about Asp.Net but you should be able to do it via JavaScript - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Yes I am looking for an alternative for `location.replace()` in JavaScript for Asp.Net core.

Comment: Replacing has nothing to do with redirecting. In any case the *server* (any server) can't directly affect the client's behavior, and browser history is 100% a client feature. Modify your target action to emit `location.replace()`

Answer (score 0):

you should try this

```
var prevUrl = Request.Headers["Referer"];
return Redirect(prevUrl);
```

Comment: Can you explain why refer does what it does?